# Change hostname to avoid broadcasting as ubuntu.local during install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I've found that during install (Ubuntu 14.04 desktop), once connected to the network, the computer is pingable (and other network activities) as ubuntu.local, via avahi-daemon. **I am looking for how to change this default hostname of "ubuntu" in the installer.** (My installer uses preseeding, and I do not have an issue setting the hostname of the installed system)

One work-around, indirect and not ideal, is to unpack the squashfs in the installer, and remove /etc/init/avahi-daemon.conf.  This avoids the broadcasting issue, and is technically a solution to my particular problem, but is not elegant.

In the squashfs, the hostname file is empty, and I haven't found where the ubuntu hostname gets set.

Other inspection, e.g. by launching xterm with `ubiquity ubiquity/success_command string xterm;` and "Trying" Ubuntu has not revealed an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything relevant to `hostname` happens in the **initrd.lz** file of the iso (at least for *16.04*). This is a cpio.lzma file. I don't know if it is meant to be changed.

- First step, HOST and USERNAME are set to some value in `scripts/casper` at line 24.
  You can change the value of HOST in `etc/casper.conf` in the **initrd.lz**
- Second step happens in `scripts/casper-bottom/18hostname` where the final `/etc/hostname` is defined and `hostname` command is called.

Comment: I found this method myself, as well, after realizing I essentially wanted to change the Live Ubuntu hostname, and then finding and skimming https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Boot_init.  The one key additional detail is to read the comments in casper.conf, and uncomment the line `export FLAVOUR="UBUNTU"` at the end of the file as well.  (Modifying the initrd.lz file was accomplished via: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd)